# Is Clojure "Java Complete"?

Tags: clojure

Please forgive the term "Java Complete" because I don't know the proper term for this.

I learned that Jython does not support 100% of Java programs. Specifically, one counterexample is that Jython does not support Java Annotations: [Jython; translating Java annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137779/jython-translating-java-annotations). You cannot take a Java program with annotations and use Jython to re-create the same program in (J)Python.

Is Clojure "Java complete"? As in, literally any program written in Java can be written in Clojure? Or are there things you can do in Java that you cannot in Clojure?

Comment: Can you? Yes, there's full parity, at least as of Java 6 (I haven't kept up since then). Will it be fun? If your Java API is a hairy one, no. But this is more a theoretical than a practical concern, just as it is for Jython (where it doesn't in practice hurt anyone to have a class with annotations written in Java as part of a larger Jython program).

Comment: See https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes#_java_annotation_support to see what the syntax looks like specifically for annotations, btw.

Comment: (so "does not support 100% of Java programs" is a bit misleading -- it's true, but only if you want to write 100% pure Jython, which there's no particular reason to do if one truly believes the "practicality beats purity" bullet point of [PEP-20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that post mentions "The most we can do, at this time, is to extend an annotated java class in Jython (assuming the class is not final), do most of your development in Jython and have the prerequisite Java container (or intermediaries) launch a Java-to-Jython shim (for example, Jython's PyServlet shim)" which didn't seem very practical.

Comment: *shrug*. Speaking only from personal experience -- I haven't had to do anything that Clojure's native Java interop didn't support *ever*, and at one point I built a Clojure interface for writing JIRA plugins (which included support for their ORM, which depended on annotations); and I still work at a Clojure shop today. But if a thin, mechanically-produced shim is going to save me a bunch of time puzzling out places where `gen-class`'s behavior isn't well-documented? I'm building that shim.

Comment: (That's *especially* true because in Clojure-land, only documented behaviors are guaranteed forward-compatible; documented interfaces are ironclad-level guaranteed to remain available and to continue to fulfil those documented promises, but relying on something that isn't explicitly documented means you're completely on your own in terms of whether your code will continue to work in the future).